# CodeMirror - getValue() no retorna nada

Tags: javascript, ide

Estoy intentando obtener el valor del textarea de code mirror pero no me devuelve nada.
Lo estoy haciendo utilizando un CDN
CSS

```
<link rel='stylesheet'
      href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/6.65.7/codemirror.min.css'>
</link>
```

Javascript

```
<script type='text/javascript'
        src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/6.65.7/codemirror.min.js'>
</script>
```

Mi contenedor div estaría de la siguiente manera

```
<div class="txtarea-code" id='code'>

</div>
```

Y el código javascript es el siguiente.

```
CodeMirror(document.querySelector('#code'), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    tabSize: 2,
    mode: 'css',
    theme: "monokai",
    indentUnit: 4,
    indentWithTabs: true,
    textWrapping: true,
    matchBrackets: true,
    autoCloseTags: true,
    autoCloseBrackets: true,
    matchTags: true,
    extraKeys: {"Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete"},
  });
```

Lo colorea sin problemas, pero a la hora de obtener su valor no me devuelve nada.
Lo obtengo de esta manera

```
let content = CodeMirror(document.querySelector('#code')).getValue();
```

He probado como dicen por ahí con -content.getDoc().getValue(), con -content.doc.getValue(), con -content.getCode(), ... y no hay manera.
Si alguien me puede decir donde está el error se lo agradezco.
Gracias de antemano !! Saludos !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te muestra el value porque no le estas seteando ninguno. Una vez que obtenes el elemento `CodeMirror` tenes que aplicarle la funcion `setValue(value)` pasandole por parametro el valor.

```js
CodeMirror(document.getElementById('code'), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    tabSize: 2,
    mode: 'css',
    theme: "monokai",
    indentUnit: 4,
    indentWithTabs: true,
    textWrapping: true,
    matchBrackets: true,
    autoCloseTags: true,
    autoCloseBrackets: true,
    matchTags: true,
    extraKeys: {"Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete"},
  });


let content = CodeMirror(document.getElementById('code'))
console.log('Antes de setear un value, content.getValue() es: ', content.getValue())
content.setValue('soy un value');
console.log("Despues de setearlo: ", content.getValue())
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.52.2/codemirror.min.css">
</link>

<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.52.2/codemirror.min.js">
</script>

<div class="txtarea-code" id="code">

</div>
```

Comment: Vale, ya lo he conseguido entender. Muchas gracias por todo.
Lo que he hecho es crear 2 objetos de CodeMirror con el id del div.
Una vez hecho esto, uno lo utilizo para obtener el valor. Ese valor se lo agrego al segundo y para finalizar muestro el valor del segundo con -getValue()
Perfecto, muchas gracias !!!!